# linux + mount USB drive in Linux

Tags: linux

I connect USB (hard disk ) to my Linux machine

the USB recognized as /dev/sdb1 ( by fdisk –l)

The hard disk include some data as images , tar files etc……

How to mount the USB? (/dev/sdb1) in order  to read the data from the USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many distros automatically mount the drive. Check under /media for example.

If not, try sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt

Answer (score 0):

First check if the usb device is already mounted as this happens automatically on most modern linux machines:

```
mount | grep sdb1
```

should if return a line indicating where the device is already mounted, if the system automatically mounted it.

You should also look at

```
dmesg | grep sdb
```

output to see if a mount wa attempted and perhaps something went wrong.

If you don't see an automated mount, create a directory under /mnt and manually mount the device there:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/usb
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
```

(you only have to create the directory the first time you try this)

check under /mnt/usb to see if the mount worked.  If not, check the dmesg output again to see if any diagnostic messages were logged.